# Variable explorer Spyder Python

Tags: python, variables, spyder

My variable explorer shows wrong "Type" and "Size" of dataframe, although showing correct fields in column "Value". See below: [image] - data3c is obviously not a Series of length 23233...but its columns are shown correctly in the last column.

When I look at the dataframe by df.iloc[:10], I see the correct dataframe in IPython console. How can I fix this issue and can I further work with the data?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error has been reported a couple of times, but unfortunately we have been unable to reproduce it in our side.

If you find a simple and reliable way to generate this problem, please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues). It'd be really appreciated.